# parallax.js only using X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax.js

I've been using a great little plugin called [parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) on a few sites, however the most recent site I've added it to it is not behaving correctly at all.

You can see it [here](http://conveyancingsupermarket.com/) functioning as intended.

but on [this](http://staging.eomfitness.com/) site it is not loading all the images and only moving on the X axis. There are no errors displaying so I'm at a loss as to why.

Has anyone had any experience with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think you haven't set the height for your element

Answer (score 0):

check the console
images are missing,.

http://staging.eomfitness.com/wp-content/themes/Starkers/layout/images/mobhead.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://staging.eomfitness.com/wp-content/themes/Starkers/css/img/lines-black.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://staging.eomfitness.com/img/snail.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)